# In matplotlib, how do you display an axis on both sides of the figure?

Tags: python, graphics, matplotlib, plot

I want to draw a plot with matplotlib with axis on both sides of the plot, similar to this plot (the color is irrelevant to this question):

[image: plot]

How can I do this with `matplotlib`?

Note: contrary to what is shown in the example graph, I want the two axis to be exactly the same, and want to show only one graph. Adding the two axis is only to make reading the graph easier.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are a couple of relevant examples in the online documentation:

- [Two Scales](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/two_scales.html) (seems to do exactly what you're asking for)
- [Dual Fahrenheit and Celsius](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/fahrenheit_celsius_scales.html)

Comment: Is there a more specialized function in the case I want the two axis to be exactly the same?

Comment: The Dual Fahrenheit and Celcius example he gave you is probably the best way to do that.  Where instead of passing the limits to a converting function you would just keep them the same.  Change it to ax2.set_ylim(y1, y2), I think that should work.

Comment: @daveydave400: sure! I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing a simpler solution :)

Comment: this is a good answer, but seems to be a ["princess in another castle"][https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer] answer to me; in-lining a self-contained answer would be, imo, a big improvement

Answer (score 76):

You can use [tick_params()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params) (this I did in [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) notebook):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bar(range(10), range(10))
tick_params(labeltop=True, labelright=True)
```

Generates this image:

[image: Bar plot with both x and y axis labeled the same]

**UPD:** added a simple example for subplots. You should use `tick_params()` with axis object.

This code sets to display only top labels for the top subplot and bottom labels for the bottom subplot (with corresponding ticks):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, axarr = plt.subplots(2)

axarr[0].bar(range(10), range(10))
axarr[0].tick_params(labelbottom=False, labeltop=True, labelleft=False, labelright=False,
                     bottom=False, top=True, left=False, right=False)

axarr[1].bar(range(10), range(10, 0, -1))
axarr[1].tick_params(labelbottom=True, labeltop=False, labelleft=False, labelright=False,
                     bottom=True, top=False, left=False, right=False)
```

Looks like this:

[image: Subplots ticks config example]

Answer (score 2):

I've done this previously using the following:

```
# Create figure and initial axis    
fig, ax0 = plt.subplots()
# Create a duplicate of the original xaxis, giving you an additional axis object
ax1 = ax.twinx()
# Set the limits of the new axis from the original axis limits
ax1.set_ylim(ax0.get_ylim())
```

This will exactly duplicate the original y-axis.

Eg:

```
ax = plt.gca()

plt.bar(range(3), range(1, 4))
plt.axhline(1.75, color="gray", ls=":")

twin_ax = ax.twinx()
twin_ax.set_yticks([1.75])
twin_ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
```

[image]

Comment: If you plot something on `ax1` it might autoscale and change independently of `ax0`, so I don't think this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.8.3/api/axes_api.html) is very helpful.  For showing the same y axis ticks and tick labels on both the left side and the right side of a plot, I have had good, consistent results with the following:

```
ax0 = ax.twinx()
ax0.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
ax0.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks(), ax.get_yticklabels(),
               fontsize= 8)
```

where ax is the default display with y's ticks and tick labels on the left.  This first line of code creates ax0 to share the x axis with ax (twinx()).  The second line sets the min and max values for ax0's y axis to match those of ax's y axis.  The last line sets ax0's y ticks and tick labels to match those of ax.

For two, separate y axes, see John Bartholomew's remarks and references above.