# How to display axis label on both sides of the figure in maptplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want X-axis to be exactly the same both at the bottom and top of my figure. While the ticklabels can be duplicated using `ax.tick_params(labeltop=True)`, it seems to be no analogous command for the label of the axis itself, as `ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')` relocates the label instead of duplicating it.

All the similar questions that I found (e.g. [In matplotlib, how do you display an axis on both sides of the figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998697/in-matplotlib-how-do-you-display-an-axis-on-both-sides-of-the-figure)) seem to be only concerned about the ticklabels, not the axis labels.

I tried using `ax.twiny()` but it adds a black frame around my plot. Is there a cleaner, minimalist way of duplicating the axis label to the other side of the figure to complement the duplicated ticklabels?

EDIT: minimal working example of the black frame added by `ax.twiny()`:

```
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ax = sns.heatmap([[0, 1], [1, 0]], cbar=None) # no outline around the heatmap
ax.twiny() # adds black frame
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Not a matplotlib expert by any means, but regarding your edit):

- `sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)` will remove the spines.
- You should be able to replicate the `xticks`, `xticklabels`, `xlim`, and `xlabel` on the twin `Axes` like so:

```
ax = sns.heatmap([[0, 1], [1, 0]], cbar=None) # no outline around the heatmap
ax.set_xlabel('foo')

ax1 = ax.twiny() # adds black frame

ax1.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks())
ax1.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels())
ax1.set_xlabel(ax.get_xlabel())
ax1.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())

sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True) # remove spines
```

[image]