# Imshow add secondary y-axis and keep format

Tags: python, imshow, twinx

I am trying to add a secondary y-axis to my imshow plot:

[Original without secondary y axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnBee.jpg)

But it wont keep the original format, i.e. i want the secondary y-axis scaled the the same as my axis on the left side.

[Trying to add secondary y axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRgfx.jpg)

Code:

```
...
axes.imshow(zi, cmap='viridis', extent=(0, 500, 0, 250), origin='lower')
ax2 = axes.twinx()
ax2.set_ylim(0, 320)
```

I tried different settings of the imshow kwargs.

Comment: Does trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63497743/6394617) help?

Comment: Alternatively, you may want to try [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html) approach, with identity functions for both the forward and inverse conversion functions.